# top first friends then the other users from like list

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have tables:

```
likes - id, user_id, like_user_id<br>
users - id, name, email ...,<br>
friends - id, user_id, friend_id, status<br>
```

Is it possible to sort it with one SQL query first to show the friends then the other users. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

I tried this and it works, but the problem is it give me double results of users:

```
select * 
from `likes` 
left join `users` on `users.id` = `likes.user_id` 
left join `friends` on `friends.user_id` = `likes.user_id` 
    or `friends.friend_id` = `likes.user_id` 
where `likes.id` = 1 
order by `friends.user_id` = 5 
    or `friends.friend_id` = 5
```

Comment: Yes, it should be possible! Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) here to **merge** the liked users with the befriended users. Upon doing this, you can create an artificial column `friend`, that you fill with `1` in the friend query and `0` in the like query. Later on you can order by that column.

```
SELECT
    friends.user_id,
    1 as friend,
    users.*
FROM
    friends
    JOIN users ON users.id = friends.friend_user_id
    UNION SELECT
            likes.user_id,
            0 as friend,
            users_liked.*
        FROM
            likes
            JOIN users as users_liked ON likes.like_user_id = users_liked.id
WHERE
    user_id = '$userId'
ORDER BY friend DESC, id ASC
```

This will return a list of all friends, followed by a list of all liked users.